# retrieve original adapter from expandablelistview with header

Tags: android, expandablelistview

I'm using a ExpandableListView with a custom adapter that extends BaseExpandableListAdapter.
Now I want to add a header to that expandable list, so instead of using my apapter to get the view of the elements I need to use the one "automatically" created with the header so I don't get a IndexOutOfBoundsExceptions because now the header is a element at 0 position.

In other ocassions where my adapter was not expandable I just need to call myList.getAdapter() and everything was ok but now I need to get the adapter that extends BaseExpandableListAdapter and I can't find the way to do it.

```
myList = (ExpandableListView)findViewById(R.id.my_list);
myList .setGroupIndicator(null);
myList .setOnGroupClickListener(this);
myList .setOnChildClickListener(this);

//add a header
View addSummaryLayout = View.inflate(this, R.layout.add_summary, null); 
groupedMultimediaListView.addHeaderView(addSummaryLayout);  

myAdapter = new MyAdapter (this, uploadingMedias);
myList .setAdapter(myAdapter );
```

At some time, I need to call the getChildView method for myAdapter (extends BaseExpandableListAdapter) but I can't use directly myAdapter because that one doesn't have the header. I need to do it through the list. I'm trying to do it through the getWrappedAdapter

```
HeaderViewListAdapter headerAdapter = ((HeaderViewListAdapter) myList .getAdapter());
((MyAdapter ) headerAdapter.getWrappedAdapter()).getChildView(0, i - 1, false, view, myList );
```

but it's giving me a ClassCastException, android.widget.ExpandableListConnector cannot be cast to MyAdapter

Does anyone know a way to get the original adapter through the list methods?

Thank you

Answer (score 40, accepted):

From the [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.html#getAdapter%28%29),

```
public ListAdapter getAdapter ()

Added in API level 1
This method should not be used, use getExpandableListAdapter().
```

so use, `getExpandableListAdapter()` and then getChildView

Comment: Thank you! I hadn't seen the warn and was driving myself mad using the other adapter!

Comment: Amazing, I was scratching my head long time. Casting getAdapter() with my custom adapter was not causing problem when using my custom function `add(CustomObject obj)`, but it was not refreshing. Saved my day!